# stucked on insert stored procedure mysql php and I couldn't figure it out of how to get roleid from dropdownlist

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I've got stuck on insert stored procedure for php since I have no idea of how to do that. Here's my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="POST">
            <label for= "FirstName">First name:<br> </label>
            <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text">
            <br>
            <label for="LastName">Last name:<br> </label>
            <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text">
            <label for="Password"><br>Password:<br> </label>
            <input id ="Password" name="Password" type="text">
            <br>
            <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address:<br></label>
            <input id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" />
            <br>
            <label for="RoleName"> Role Name:<br> </label>
           <!-- creating the dropdownlist called rolename and I got stuck 
            stuck on how to get roleid -->
            <select name='RoleName'> 
                <?php             
  //connect to database
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "construction", "3306");

  //run the store procedure
  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, 
     "CALL getallroles") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());  //run your query

  $select = $_POST['RoleName'];
 // echo "<select name='RoleName'>"; // list box select command

    //looping for all of the role names
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {  $select.='<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';

  }
           echo $select;// Closing of list box

                ?>
            </select>
            <br><br>
           <!-- <input type="submit" -->
            <button type ="submit" value="Submit">Insert
            </button>
            <!-- I will be calling the insert stored procedure where I will be passing the parameters unfortunately it didn't work at all and I wasn't able to figure it out of how to get roleid from dropdownlist without showing it -->

            <?php

             //connect to database
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "construction", "3306");

   //checking to make sure the textbox are not empty
  if (!empty($_GET))
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];



  //$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
//  $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
   if (!empty($_GET))
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
 // $Password = $_POST['Password'];
   if (!empty($_GET))
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
//  $select = $_POST['RoleName'];
   if (!empty($_GET))
    $select = $_POST['RoleName'];
//this one is for creating hashing passwords
  $options = ['cost' => 12,];
  $iSalt = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
  //hashing the passwords
  $Password2 =password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
  $EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

  //Having trouble with insert stored procedure in which i've never done that part before   
//I'm trying to get the mysql_insert_id to work but it didn't work at all.

            $sql2 = mysqli_query($connection, 
     "CALL registerusers(mysql_insert_id()),$FirstName,$LastName,$Password2,$EmailAddress,$iSalt,$select)") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());  //run your query


            ?>




</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my mysql code for getallroles stored procedure

```
    DELIMITER @@
    DROP PROCEDURE getallroles @@
    CREATE PROCEDURE construction.getallroles
    ()
    BEGIN

  select RoleName,RoleID from roles;

End @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, here's the insert stored procedure in mysql for registerusers stored procedure

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE registerusers @@
CREATE PROCEDURE construction.registerusers
(OUT `UserID` TINYINT(11), IN `iFirstName` VARCHAR(30), IN `iLastName` VARCHAR(30), IN `iPassword` VARCHAR(30), IN `iEmailAddress` VARCHAR(30), IN `iSalt` VARCHAR(40), IN `iRoleID` VARCHAR(1))
BEGIN
  declare checkexistingemailaddress varchar(30);

  select emailaddress into checkexistingemailaddress
from users
where emailaddress = iEmailaddress;


    If(iFirstName ='') then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';


    Elseif(iLastName='') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Last Name';

     Elseif(iPassword='') then
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Password';

   Elseif(iEmailAddress='') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Email Address';
  Elseif(iEmailaddress=checkexistingemailaddress ) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Address already exists';

 Elseif(iEmailaddress not RLIKE'^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9._-]@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9].[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$') then
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please enter the corerct email address';

    else

    insert into users(

    FirstName,
     LastName ,
     Password ,
     EmailAddress ,
     Salt ,
     RoleID 
     )
    Values
    (
    iFirstName,
     iLastName ,
     iPassword ,
     iEmailAddress ,
     iSalt ,
     iRoleID 
    );
    set UserID = last_insert_id();  
     end if;

    End @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Here's the picture of what the website looks like
[image]

Comment: `<form method="POST">` and `if (!empty($_GET))` don't fit together.

Answer (score 0):

Your $_POST['FirstName'] gets sent AFTER the form is submitted, not when the page loads. There won't be any values in POST fields, which is why you're getting the error.

Call the PHP script after the form gets sent IMO

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by call" PHP script after the form gets sent IMO??""

Comment: if (isset($_POST['FirstName'])) {
//do something
}

Run this check prior to accessing any $_POST variables and you'll find none have been sent. You must transmit the form data prior to being able to use $_POST variables.

Comment: IMO => in my opinion.